# Encyclopedia of properties of nonnegative matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, nonnegative-matrices

I'd like to buy a book that contains more or less all known properties of elementwise nonnegative nonnegative matrices, i.e. matrices $A$ such that $a_{ij} \ge 0$ for all $1 \le i,j \le n$.

- Chapter 8 in [Matrix Analysis](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/matrix-analysis-2nd-edition) of Johnson and Horn is nice but far to be exhaustive.
- In [Matrix Analysis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387948461) of Bhatia and [Matrix Computations](https://jhupbooks.press.jhu.edu/content/matrix-computations) of Golub and Van Loan there is not even a chapter dedicated to this class of matrices.

After a bit googling I found these two books:

- It seems that [Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971262) of Berman and Plemmons is exactly what I want. But it is more than 20 years old (1994), so I wonder if there is something more *up-to-date*.
- [Nonnegative Matrices and Applications](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511529979) looks quite nice too and is a little bit more recent (1997). However, it seems that it is less oriented on the properties of nonnegative matrices themselves rather than their applications.

So, I'm a bit puzzled and my question is the following:

> If I want to buy 1 book collecting the most complete list of known properties of nonnegative matrices, which one should I get?

Comment: To avoid confusions (and it seems there have been some), I'd recommend making it explicit that you are after **elementwise nonnegative** matrices.

Comment: Bapat's book is pretty much the closest to what you are seeking. I am not aware of another book that matches your requirements. Hence my answer is: $\emptyset$

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the books you list, there is also the book *[Nonnegative Matrices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471839663)* by H. Minc (1974), but it is outdated and out of print.

Also, the book *[Combinatorial Matrix Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/combinatorial-matrix-theory/599A61CE4A2F6A8317867795AA29D9D6)* by Brualdi and Ryser does a nice treatment of the *combinatorial structure* of nonnegative matrices (and complex matrices in general).

IMHO, a new textbook on nonnegative matrices is long overdue (an entire monograph could be devoted to the *[nonnegative inverse eigenvalue problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10992)* alone).

Answer (score 5):

Positive matrices are only one side of a more general subject, that of *Totally positive matrices*. So you can be interested in the books written by Allan Pinkus (Cambridge Univ. Press, 2010) or by Shaun Fallat & Charles Johnson (Princeton niv. Press, 2011).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure to understand how *Positive matrices are only one side of [...] Totally positive matrices*. It seems to me that $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is a positive matrix which is not totally positive (its determinant is strictly negative).

Comment: @Surb. Precisely, that's the point. Total positivity means that $A$ is positive, and it induces positive matrices when acting on the exterior algebra. This implies that, not only $A$ has a positive real eigenvalue, but all its eigenvalues are positive (the converse is false).

Comment: As I understand this the "totally positive matrix" are a subset of the OP's nonnegative matrices. So I think the qualification in this answer *"...of a more **general** subject,..."* is a bit misleading.

Comment: I agree with @Gottfried Helms, the set of totally positive matrices seems to be a subset of the set of entrywise nonnegative matrices. Thus I don't see why > positive matrices are just one side of a more general subject, that of Totally positive matrices. At the same time I don't see the relation between entrywise nonnegative (positive) matrices and nonnegative (or positive) eigenvalues, neither their real part (except, of course, for the spectral radius). For instance, consider the matrix $E$ made by all ones. (cont.)

Comment: The matrix $A = E -\epsilon I$, is a positive matrix for any $0<\epsilon <1$ and its eigenvalues are $n-\epsilon >0$ (simple Perron eigenvalue) and $-\epsilon$ with multiplicity $n-1$. So $A$ has $n-1$ negative eigenvalues.